# phpredis + pconnect

Tags: php, multithreading, webserver, redis, connection-pooling

I am using phpredis on my php based website. The webserver I am using is a the simplest apache apt-get installation, no configuration involved, as this is only a development environment.

The issue I am facing is that basically, while using phpredis, there is no difference between "connect" and "pconnect" commands: they both create a new connection everytime, as I can see from the "info" command on redis-cli.

Now, I am pretty sure it is because of the apache configuration and the fact that it probably (most likely) is a multi-threaded env, therefore can't enstablish a single connection.

My question is basically for when I will turn into production: what would the best choice of a webserver be to avoid this problem? I remember using lighttpd with thousands of users and still get only a very few (like 2 or 3) connections on mongoDB.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 I'd like to know what are the specific minimum settings/environment necessary to correctly use persistent connections with phpredis aswell.

Comment: pconnect creates a persistent connection. I have used it in a symfony2 service.